# Understanding edge correction with a 2nd order polynomial in Gaussian filter

Tags: polynomials, normal-distribution

I am trying to understand the following code from ImageJ: http://pastebin.com/tXfhNxqf

**The problem:**

When computing the gaussian kernel we use the gaussian function

$$ f(x) = e^{-\dfrac{x^2}{2 \sigma^2}} $$

for a given $\sigma$, and it is common to take a radius $R = R(\sigma)$ and compute only the components until that $R$ (in order to make computations finite). In the code $R$ is computed in the line 27.

If we take as the new function $\hat{f}(x) = f(x), \, |x| < R$ and $\hat{f}(x) = 0$ elsewhere, we have a step at $x = R$ which leads to problems. In order to fix this, a common aproach is to replace the near-edge values by a 2nd order polynomial $p(x)$ which is $0$ at $x = R$ and satisfy $p(r) = f(r), \, p'(r) = f'(r)$ for some $0 < r < R$.

(This is also explained in the source code, as a comment).

How to find this polynomial?

**My solution:**

Let $p(x) = a x^2 + bx + c $ , then we have to solve the system:

$$ \begin{cases}
p(r) = f(r) \\
p'(r) = f'(r) \\
p(R) = 0 \\ 
p'(R) = 0
\end{cases}$$

for the unknowns $a,b,c,r.$

**What I think the code does:**

Let $p(x) = a^2 (x-R)^2$, this already satisfy $p(R)=0, \,p'(R) = 0$. Then we have $p(r) = f(r)$ which implies $a^2 (x-R)^2 = f(r)$ solving for $a$, $a(r) = \frac{\sqrt{f(r)}}{R-r}$ (line 38, where kernel[0][r] is $f(r)$ and kRadius is $R$).

Then it takes r such that a(r) is minimum.

How is this a solution to the original problem?

Comment: I have rolled back your post to the previous edit. Please do not delete the body of your question - it is confusing to those who view your question, and often is considered rude to those who answer it. Is there any particular reason why you want to delete your question (especially in light of the fact that you have accepted an answer)?

Comment: @AWertheim there is, I have flagged the question and ask for a moderator

Comment: **Do not attempt to deface your own question.**  As you can see, we can always revert it, so it's pointless anyway.

Comment: @Trollkemada: Ok. That being the case, a moderator can help you. In the future though, please try to avoid this practice, and flag a moderator before editing your question. As I noted, this is widely regarded as rude to people who answer your question, and I believe is against MSE policy (I could be wrong here, though).

Comment: @heropup AWertheim Sorry about that then, I will wait for a moderator to answer. I didn't mean to be rude to WimC, who helped me with the problem, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct formula for $a(r)$ is $$ a(r)=\frac{f(r)^{\tfrac{1}{2}}}{R-r} $$ (note that $R > r$). Now $a(r)$ minimal implies $a'(r)=0$.  Computing the derivative results in $$ a'(r) = a(r)\left(\frac{f'(r)}{2f(r)}+\frac{1}{R-r}\right).$$  So $a(r)$ minimal implies that $$ f'(r)=\frac{-2f(r)}{R-r}. $$  The derivative of $p$ is $p'(x) = -2a(r)^2(R-x)$ and setting $x= r$ results in $$ p'(r)=\frac{-2f(r)}{R-r}=f'(r) $$ so the derivatives of $p$ and $f$ coincide at $r$ as required.